# my firebase function is being deleted when i try to upload new one

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I want to create a function for a push notification but when I try to upload new function then the previous function which is for different purpose is being deleted . I don't know why currently I have 3 functions. [This is the screenshot of my node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiT9C.png)

Comment: are you removing any function form the `.js` file before deploying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way deployments with the Firebase CLI work by default.  Every time you deploy, all the functions you deploy completely replace any other functions you previously deployed.

If you want to deploy only certain functions without replacing everything, you need to specify that on the command line [as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#partial_deploys):

> When deploying functions, you can target specific ones:
>
> ```
> firebase deploy --only functions:function1
> firebase deploy --only functions:function1,functions:function2
> ```

Comment: oh man how can I thank you ,, it worked . finally a great solution. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you renamed the previous function in the index file.

That would show up as a "delete" prompt when deploying.

If that is not the case, please include the index.js / index.ts file.